# Wordpress get theme name from stylesheet

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, stylesheet

I want to get wordpress theme name from stylesheet (style.css).

For example here is style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Campus
Theme URI: http://www.academiathemes.com/themes/campus/
Description: Campus is a free WordPress theme for blogs and review websites.
Author: AcademiaThemes.com
Author URI: http://www.academiathemes.com/
Version: 1.2.6
License: GNU General Public License v2.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: blue, white, light, two-columns, right-sidebar, fixed-layout, responsive-layout, custom-background, custom-menu, featured-images, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready
Text Domain: campus
*/
```

"Theme Name: Campus" must be stored in PHP variable.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this?:

$var = wp_get_theme();

Comment: Docs on wp_get_theme: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme

Answer (score 0):

wp_get_theme() works but get_stylesheet() is faster.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet/